# C# Azure Custom domain with storage account

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I recently found a possibility to connect my own domain to my azure storage account. And my question is, I would like to know if there is a possibility to get this custom domain address using the Azure Storage SDK?

I am currently using my blob account to store images, and I would like to have a direct link to each of the images with my custom domain in the URL. And I would love to have it taken out straight from the SDK, but I don't know if it is possible, or how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question, no, there's no programmatic way to get the custom domains associated with storage accounts.